# asp.net Post & Submit Form to another site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, post

I am tring send data to another website's form from my 'Web Form' and submit it. But I couldn't achive it so far. I tried add id's bodyContent_ tag but still no progress. Can you detect where I am doing it wrong ? Thank You

```
        protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(PostForm().ToString());
        this.PostScript(Page);
    }

    public string PostForm()
    {

        string PostUrl = "http://www.teknobilsoft.com/Contact.aspx";
        string Method = "post";

        string name = "John";
        string email = "john@doe.com";
        string subject = "Mesaj";    
        string message = "some messages";   



        StringBuilder ppForm = new StringBuilder();


        ppForm.AppendFormat("<form  id='form1' action='{0}' method='{1}'>", PostUrl, Method);
        ppForm.AppendFormat("<input  id='txtName' value='{0}'>", name);
        ppForm.AppendFormat("<input  id='txtEmail' value='{0}'>", email);
        ppForm.AppendFormat("<input  id='ddlSubject' value='{0}'>", subject);
        ppForm.AppendFormat("<textarea  id='txtMessage' value='{0}'></textarea>", message);      
        ppForm.Append("</form>");

        return ppForm.ToString();
    }

    private void PostScript(System.Web.UI.Page Page)
    {

        StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
        strScript.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
        strScript.Append("var ctlForm = document.getElementById('form1');");
        strScript.Append("ctlForm.submit();");
        strScript.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "btnSendMessage", strScript.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the error message do you get?

Also, is there a reason why you use JavaScript to post the data? You can post using HttpWebRequest in C#:

http://www.stickler.de/information/code-snippets/httpwebrequest-post-data.aspx